# how hadoop decide datanode free space

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop.

So, I am assuming and it seems obvious that hadoop will have to keep track of the free space in each datanode.
For the reason being, if new file saving request comes to hadoop, hadoop system will have to decide which datanodes to choose to store the incoming file.

Now, each datanode keeps the data in location given by config : dfs.datanode.data.dir.

So I can set any directory location in this config.

Let us assume I set, D:/data/hadoop

Now how hadoop calculate free space in this directory? As there is no concept called "free space in directory". Does hadoop consider free space available in D: drive in this example, as total free space in datanode?